# Sending a string and hexidecimal to the comport

Tags: string, serial-port, hex

I am attempting to send the string "QZ1" to the comport; however the receiving unit's manual requires that "Each command string sent to the receiver must start with an {*}(hex 2A) and be terminated with a carriage return {cr}(hex 0D)."  I've gone through a number of different iterations without success.

Would someone kindly steer me in the write direction as to how best send the string to the comport prefacing the string with {*}(hex 2A) and ending with a carriage return {cr}(hex 0D)?

Comment: What's a [comport](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comport)?

Comment: On output, a comport (officially: COM port) accepts one 8-bit character from a program and sends it on one single output wire as a string of bits, low-order bit first. On input, it reads an incoming string of bits from a remotely-sourced wire, collects those bits into one 8-bit character, and delivers it to a program in that form. So its job on output is to serialize and send one 8-bit character; and on input to receive and parallelize one 8-bit character. A COM port usually comprises a full-duplex UART (Universal Asynchronous Receiver-Transmitter). The Intel 8251 was one of the first UARTs.

Comment: Thank you for your help Pete.  Unfortunately, the receiver hangs when I write the string ( _XMR3Comport.Write("*SV\r") ) to the comport.  The manual says that "A terminating {cr} must end each command, even if multiple commands are sent back to back."  Although I can't be sure, I wonder if the receiver is looking for the carriage-return in hex and doesn't recognize the carriage-return string-value "\r".  Could there be any other format to write the string to the comport?  Thanks very much once again, Pete.

Comment: Pete - You were correct.  It turned out that I had set the comport Handshake incorrectly and once I changed it to the appropriate setting, everything worked great.  Thanks for your help.  Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be confusing what with the switch from characters to their hex representations and back. Here's what to do. Don't worry that the doc says "hex this and hex that." Just

1. send the character '*'
2. send the character 'Q'
3. send the character 'V'
4. send the character '\r' for a carriage return

So you'd store in a C-string: "*QV\r" and send from that.

HTH. If not, ask some more.

Answer (score 0):

as i can get you only have to add 2 byte to the string you are sending for exmaple `hello` would change to `*hello\r` note that 2A is hex for ascii character * and 0D representation of \r in charmap